# General programming, 2d array, whats wrong with a double for loop?

Tags: performance, language-agnostic, for-loop, coding-style

This is a general programming question.

I have seen on a lot of posts that iterating through a 2d array via a double for loop is "horrible" "ugly" etc... Why is this?

Are arrays not an efficient data structure compared to dictionaries and such, and also is not a double for loop more efficient than a foreach or other alternative?
Also if your using a 2d array you are often dealing with a 2d coordinate system. The x and y positions are already "built in" to the data structure as the indexes of the arrays (so you dont need to add ,say, a tuple as a dictionary key)  and by changing the for loop paramaters you can very cheaply iterate through different parts of your grid while totally ignoring the parts you dont want to iterate through. For example to avoid the "outer" rows and columns you could do..

```
for (int x = 1; x < Grid.GetLength(0)-1; x++)
{
        for (int y = 1; y < Grid.GetLength(1)-1; y++)
        {
            Grid[x,y].DoSomething();
        }
}
```

With a foreach you'd iterate through *everything* in the collection and then have something to check whether it is in the coordinate range you want.

Comment: If you're doing something to every element, yes; if you're trying to find a particular element, then it's not very efficient at all.

Comment: Do you have any examples of any of "a lot of posts" that say this?

Comment: No, sorry I didnt keep any links but it has been a recurring theme for me. Ive seen quite a few posts here.. Also one of my lecturers and I noticed at coderetreat everyone seemed to regard multidimensional arrays and multiple for loops as "dirty" and they would always use higher lvl structures like dictionaries, lists and whatnot

Comment: That's probably because 2D array is a more complex structure than a standard 1D array. As such, it implies a "higher-level" usage, but it supports only the operations of 1D array and lacks the advantages of higher-level structures, such as dictionary. As far as performance concerned, 2D array most probably will perform faster than the alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with 2 loops for iterating a 2D array, as long as this is what you really need to do.
One thing to note is performance - in general, the looping should follow the layout of the array in memory. E.g., if the 2D array is stored as a 1D memory buffer where row `n` is stored after row `n-1` (this is the common implementation in general purpose languages), the external loop should go through the rows and internal one through the columns. This way cache misses are minimized.

In general, effectiveness of array access compared to other methods completely depends on particular language implementation. Usually, the array would be the most primitive data structure, resulting in the fastest access. BTW, dictionary is a generalization of array concept.

Comment: See [Row-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) for a good discussion of how multi-dimensional arrays can be laid out, including some per-language examples.

Comment: +1 for a good answer right up to that last line.  -1 for the idea that a dictionary is a generalized array.  A dictionary is a lookup table, a vastly different concept from an array.

Comment: @RossPatterson Dictionary is a synonym for `associative array` concept: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array . In a standard array the key is index and the data is pointed by the index (the key).

Comment: Yes, dictionaries are a variety of associative array.  But associative arrays are not arrays.  They're only vaguely similar enough to inherit the name.  And they're certainly unrelated to the question at hand.

Comment: @RossPatterson 1. Dictionary *is* an associative array, not a variety. 2. Each array is an associative array (but not vice versa), i.e. private case of it. This can be easily proved using mathematical logic, by formalizing what I've pointed out in my previous comment. 3. Dictionaries are very much related to the question. Understanding that dictionary is a generalization of array concept leads to understanding the reasons what pros/cons each of them has when compared.